# I want to only copy list of records from csv1 file to newFile.csv whose first row item starting with letter is 'A'

Tags: python-3.x, csv

***This is code***

I want only first item word is 'A' data stored in newFile.csv file. How i can Do?

student_databaseOne = 'firstFile.csv'

NewFile = 'NewFile.csv'

```
letter = 'A'
with open(student_databaseOne, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        for item in row:
            if item == 'A':
                for row in reader:
                   with open(NewFile, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                      writer = csv.writer(f)
                      writer.writerows(row)
```

Comment: Having the write in the loop will create larger amount of IO. Consider collecting the rows in a data type (list, etc.) and then dumping to a file after all the looping. If you want to keep it in the loop you will want to 'a'ppend.

Answer (score 0):

This script will read the `firstFile.csv` row by row, and when the first item is equal to `A` it stores the row into `NewFile.csv`:

```
import csv

with open('firstFile.csv', 'r') as f_in, open('NewFile.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for first, *rest in reader:
        if first == 'A':
            writer.writerow([first, *rest])
```